# Write data to Mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

Currently we are using

```
@collection.update id, c_doc, upsert: true, safe: true
```

Does setting the **safe** flag to True confirms that the data is actually written to the slaves and then written or it just confirms that the data is written to primary?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/wiki/Write-Concern) wiki address your question?

Answer (score 0):

safe = true means that the primary has acknowledged the write. It is not guaranteed to be replicated to slaves yet, nor is it safe to assume it's stored on disk. The documentation at https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/wiki/Write-Concern explains the different write concerns.

None of the w= options confirm writing to disk, for that you need "fsync=1". But you really should not be using that as it hurts performance.

Comment: I am using the default write concern which is 1 for 1.8 and above. I think writeconcern=1 confirms write to disk. Please confirm.

Comment: @Sandeep - read the wiki that I linked to in my comment above (and Derick apparently linked to as well). Write 1 is one disk, not replicas.